# setting alias on mysql columns with math operators

Tags: mysql, sql, operators, alias

This is my sql query where i am getting an error at the AS statement.

```
select a.*, b.*, (a.date - b.date) AS before
from tbl A a join tbl B b
on a.id = b.id
where (a.date - b.date) < 5 and (a.date - b.date)  > 0;
```

How can i make my SQL query like this and working?

```
select a.*, b.*, (a.date - b.date) AS before
from tbl A a join tbl B b
on a.id = b.id
where before < 5 and before > 0;
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Just a comment, you can use the `BETWEEN` operator to avoid having both less than/greater than conditions.

Comment: @McAdam331 `BETWEEN` is inclusive.

Comment: @Uueerdo good point, thanks. So, in OP's case, it would be `BETWEEN 1 and 4`. Still doable, but should be noted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`before` is a reserved word.  Use something else or use backticks:

```
select a.*, b.*, (a.date - b.date) AS datediff
from tbl A a join
     tbl B b
     on a.id = b.id
where (a.date - b.date) < 5 and (a.date - b.date)  > 0;
```

The list of reserved words is [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html).  `Before` is used in the definition of triggers (and perhaps other places).

EDIT:

For your second question, you can use a `having` clause if you really want:

```
select a.*, b.*, (a.date - b.date) AS datediff
from tbl A a join
     tbl B b
     on a.id = b.id
having datediff < 5 and datediff > 0;
```

This is a MySQL extension to `having`.  It looks really awkward to anyone who is not familiar with it (it is just screaming, "where is the `group by`").  But, it can be useful, particularly for longer, more complicated expressions.

Comment: First you answered faster than me, and edited faster than I could comment with the reserved words. I'd give you +2 for speed if I could.

Comment: Oh, that typing class I took in tenth grade was probably the most useful class I ever took.

Comment: and i thought it was something to do with the math operators..thank you - i learnt something new today!

Answer (score 0):

Can see a few issues:
1) 1st query...'before' is a reserved word.  You can't use it as an alias.  Call your column something else.
2) 2nd query... you won't be able to reference the alias within the same query. 
3) You are looking for results that are LESS THAN 5 AND GREATER THAN 0?

Comment: I don't understand why your point number three is a problem, unless you're referring to the fact that they're dates, values less than 5 and greater than 0 do exist.

Comment: Yes but I would think they would cancel each other out...shouldn't it be an OR instead?

Comment: No, I think they're doing what they want. Consider it equivalent to: `WHERE column IN(1, 2, 3, 4)` because that's essentially what it's doing, if that makes it more clear to you.

Comment: OMG you are right.. I was flipping the '>' and '<' symbols in my head. Time for a coffee